# Macro Bulder MS Access Insert textbox value into msgbox

Tags: ms-access, macros, textbox, ms-access-2007, msgbox

I have a macro built through the macro builder that has a msgbox that says "success, you've been assigned task number:" I would like the task number taken from a "tboTaskNumber" to follow this message.

I can easily do this in VBA, however I am really struggling putting this in the Macro Builder (in vba you could do something like `"Success..." & Me.tboTaskNumber.Value`. But it appears the "Message" field on the macro builder msgbox action adds quotes at the beginning and end of the "Message" by default.

What is the syntax that can solve this in the macro builder?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert into an expression using equals:

```
=""Success..."&[tboTaskNumber]
```

It doesn't require `Me` as the macro is embedded in the form.

If the macro wasn't embedded then it would require:

```
=""Success..."&Forms![frmName]![tboTaskNumber]
```